# Why does ttk.Button appears in the main window instead of tk.Toplevel?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a main UI which gets instantiated like this:

```
class MyApp(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        (...)

    def make_gui(self):
        (...)
        self.helpButt = ttk.Button(self.InnerRightFrm2, padding=(0, 0),
                                   text='Help', image=help_icon
                                   compound='left', command=self.show_help)
        (...)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Myapp')
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.resizable(True, True)
    root.update()
    gui = MyApp(root)
    gui.mainloop()
```

When a user clicks `Show help` button located on the main interface a new `Toplevel` window should appear. The `Toplevel` of this window contains two frames: `topFrame0` on `row=0` and `topFrame1` on `row=1`. I create a third frame inside `topFrame1` to put "Close" Button in in. Here is how I do it:

```
def show_help():
    top_win = tk.Toplevel()
    top_win.title('Help')
    top_win.resizable(0, 0)

    topFrame0 = ttk.Frame(top_win, borderwidth=2, relief='groove')
    topFrame0.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    topFrame1 = ttk.Frame(top_win, borderwidth=2, relief='flat')
    topFrame1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    buttonFrame = ttk.Frame(topFrame1, borderwidth=2, relief='groove').grid()
    ttk.Button(buttonFrame, padding=(0, 2), text='Close', command=top_win.destroy).grid(sticky='e')
```

However, instead of appearing in the right botton of `Toplevel` window (notice red arrow in the screenshot), "Close" Button appears in the right bottom of the main `MyApp` window! How can this even happen?

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a runnable shortended example in order to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In line

```
buttonFrame = ttk.Frame(...).grid()
```

you assign `None` to `buttonFrame` because `grid()` returns `None` so you have later `ttk.Button(None, ...)` and you add button to main window.

You need

```
buttonFrame = ttk.Frame(...)
buttonFrame.grid()
```